# How does ADS-B get pressure altitude?

Tags: ads-b, transponder, mode-c

I have learned that ADS-B out broadcasts both Pressure altitude and GPS Altitude.

GPS altitude is, obviously, available from the GPS, but where and how does it determine pressure altitude? Does it broadcast *uncorrected* pressure altitude as is broadcast by Transponder Mode C, or is it QNH-corrected as displayed on an altimeter?

Comment: Uncorrected pressure altitude as per this answer: [Does baro altitude from ADSB represent height above ground level or height above mean sea level?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/95817/19)