# Mode S Transmission from Boeing 737 Integrated Standby Flight Display (ISFD) data?

Tags: air-traffic-control, boeing-737, ads-b, transponder, mode-s

During a recent flight, while in communication with London control*, we received a query about our RVSM (Reduced Vertical Separation Minima) compliance. Both the Captain's and First Officer's altimeters were set to STD - and within 20ft of each other - which left us curious as to why the controller asked about our RVSM capability. However, during a subsequent check, we noticed that our Integrated Standby Flight Display (ISFD) was not set to STD, it had been inadvertently overlooked after departure.

Does the Integrated Standby Flight Display (ISFD) on our aircraft (Boeing 737) transmit information via Mode S to air traffic controllers? I couldn't find any reference to this in the Boeing Flight Crew Operations Manual (FCOM). Could the controller's query about RVSM compliance be related to our ISFD oversight, or are these two issues unrelated?

**Just feel that it is important to note that they are exceptionally good controllers.*

Comment: The Mode S transponder transmits *uncorrected* pressure altitude (see e.g. [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95806/does-baro-altitude-from-adsb-represent-height-above-ground-level-or-height-above)). Your QNH/STD setting shouldn't have any impact on the transmission.